# Enviar email para todos os registrados

Tags: php, email

Como posso enviar um email para cada um dos utilizadores registrados na base de dados?

Desta forma só consigo enviar para um utilizador, neste caso é enviado um email para o último user da bd.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user`"; 
    $query = $mysqli->query( $sql ); 
    if( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {

         while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
             $email[]=$row['email'];
             $u=$row['username'];    
         }

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "Assunto";
        $txt = "texto exemplo";

        $headers = "From: suporte@localhost" . "\r\n" .
        "CC: suporte@localhost";

        mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

    } else {

    }
?>
```

Comment: Como vc quer fazer? um email para cada pessoa ou um email para todo mundo?

Comment: um email para cada pessoa @rray

Comment: Joga o `mail()` dentro do while então.

Comment: certíssimo @rray :)

Comment: Opa, só alguns comentários que você deveria se atentar. Quantos e-mails são? Onde a aplicação está hospeda vai suportar o envio? Não existe limites de disparo por hora? Se não ver esses detalhes você pode simplesmente bloquear o envio de e-mail do servidor. Entre outros, como colocar o domínio em black list e por aí vai...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo como no exemplo abaixo. Seu problema era que a função mail estava fora do laço, desta forma ela só seria excutada uma unica vez. Dentro do while ela enviará um email para cada registro.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user`"; 
$query = $mysqli->query( $sql ); 

if( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {

    $headers = "From: suporte@localhost"."\r\n"."CC: suporte@localhost";

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {


        mail($row['email'], "Assunto", "texto exemplo", $headers);
    }
}
```

Recomendo ler e utilizar o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)